# How to add float together as actual numerical values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an app and part of it requires adding values together.

I have a form where a user can enter a dollar amount which allows floats i.e. `55.25` etc... When a a new item is submitted via the form, the totals get added together. Using whole numbers is easy but I want float numbers to be added together on each form submission. The struggle is that to get numbers to display I use `parseFloat().toFixed(2)` but adding strings together just gives a string value not a mathematical/decimal value.

How can I achieve this?

```
totalAmount(() => {
        let totalPayment = '0.00';

        if (items.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            let item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items[i]));

            totalPayment = parseFloat(totalPayment) + parseFloat(item.amount).toFixed(2);
          }
        }

        return totalPayment;
      }),
```

Input field

```
<input type="number" required min="0" id="amount" step=0.01>
```

Comment: _"but adding strings together just gives a string"_ - Then don't make them strings

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items[i]));` - What is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Andreas It creates a deep copy of items[i], but I think this step is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @kol I know what it does... The question is for OP because I'm interested in what OP tries to do/fix with that construct.

Comment: @Andreas OK, sorry.

Comment: @Andreas that was accidentally left from testing. I removed it and am getting just the indexed item. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a + sign before each item to transform it to numerical and then .toFixed the result

```
totalPayment = (+totalPayment + +item.amount).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Why should OP constantly convert strings to numbers and back to strings? The only sane solution: don't make them strings until the very end...

Answer (score 2):

Add first, then format with `toFixed`:

```
totalPayment = parseFloat(totalPayment) + parseFloat(item.amount);
totalPayment = totalPayment.toFixed(2);
```

Or:

```
totalPayment = parseFloat(totalPayment) + parseFloat(item.amount);
return totalPayment.toFixed(2);
```